# Specify Serial No. in mysql while function

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, autonumber

```
while ($one = mysql_fetch_array($two)) {
<td>Want Serial No Here</td> 
<td><?=$something['something']?></td>
}
```

I want to autonumber Serial No. .. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the impression that you are trying to generate a consecutive number for each row:

```
<?php

$count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $count++;

    echo '<tr><td>' . $count . '</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['name']) . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MySQL` does not support `rownum` / `row_number` natively.

You could emulate it using session variables:

```
SET @r := 0;

SELECT  @r := @r + 1 AS rownum, t.*
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        myfield
```

, or better, just use a `PHP` variable:

```
<?
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>
 <td><?= ++$i ?></td> 
 <td><?=$row['serial_no']?></td>
<? } ?>
```